# Is a tag edit substantial enough?

Tags: support, tags

When I want to edit a tag of a question I get following message:

> Your edit will be placed in a queue until it is peer reviewed.
>
> We welcome all constructive edits, but please make them substantial. Avoid trivial, tiny one-letter edits unless absolutely necessary.

Now the question is: are tag edits (adding a needed tag to an under-untagged, replacing a mis-used tag) substantial enough?

For example the **proc**-tag-wiki is just about a Ruby feature called proc - but currenlty some questions about Oracle Pro*C (a embedded SQL preprocessor) or the Linux `/proc` filesystem are also tagged with **proc**. Btw, what tag should be used for `/proc`?

Say I come across a Pro*C Question which is tagged with **proc** - is a change to **proc-sql** considered substantial or not?

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII, hm? I have ~ 1900 rep and I get the above message ...

Comment: Tag edits are encouraged. @RichardJ.RossIII, think `xcode`, am I rite...

Comment: @H2CO3 sometimes I think that tag should be blacklisted...

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Exactly... But I'm afraid of posting such a feature request on Meta, I would loose all my rep...

Comment: @H2CO3 Meta rep is like unicorns - it all goes away due to bounty hunters. But seriously, I would back such a change, definitely.

Comment: @H2CO3 Or SE could hire a SWAT team of 30 people to police the tag all day, every day.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(Even though this notification is anomalous, I'll answer the idea of your question.)

We prefer it when you improve as much of a post's content as possible. However, we don't expect you to - as such, all constructive edits are appreciated.

In the case of tag cleanups and retags, it is more heavily emphasized to improve the content of a post. If the posts are older, they will draw less attention, so are less likely to be edited in the future. Also, retagging bumps posts to the top of the active feed, so is not recommended to do en-masse without some content improvement.

In short: while we want people to retag and cleanup, please give the posts a quick scan to see if there's anything which obviously needs fixing. It would be appreciated.